# Save image to another server

Tags: php, image-processing

I currently create and save a custom image using the function below. This works perfectly and saves the image to my server.

```
function merge($filename_x, $filename_y, $filename_result) {

 // Get dimensions for specified images
 list($width_x, $height_x) = getimagesize($filename_x);
 list($width_y, $height_y) = getimagesize($filename_y);

 // Create new image with desired dimensions
 $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width_x + $width_y, $height_x);

 // Load images and then copy to destination image
 $image_x = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename_x);
 $image_y = imagecreatefromgif($filename_y);

 imagecopy($image, $image_x, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_x, $height_x);
 imagecopy($image, $image_y, $width_x, 0, 0, 0, $width_y, $height_y);

 // Save the resulting image to disk (as JPEG)
 imagejpeg($image, $filename_result);

 // Free memory
 imagedestroy($image);
 imagedestroy($image_x);
 imagedestroy($image_y);
}
```

Use:

```
$img1 = '/folder1/folder2/image1.gif';
$img2 = '/folder1/folder2/image2.gif';
$destination = '/dirabc/dirdef/finalImage.jpeg';
merge($img1 , $img2 , $destination );
```

The issue is, how could I save this image to another server I own?

Comment: use ftp function in php to send the file to another server? http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_ftp_put.asp

Comment: @Valkyriee what file? At what point in my code could it be considered a file to transfer? thanks.

Comment: What file? are u asking me? the image you are about to send to another server. the link clearly explains and have an example :)

Comment: file, image ... it's all the same